# Coding error on BaseMacLayer

Tags: c++, veins

When building the Veins (Version:4.4) on Omnet version `omnetpp-5.1pre2-src-windows`, I get the following error output:

```
**19:58:05 **** Incremental Build of configuration gcc-release for project veins ****
make MODE=release all 
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/Users/SIA/Omnet/omnetpp-5.1pre2-src-windows/omnetpp-5.1pre2/samples/veins/src'
veins/base/modules/BaseMacLayer.cc
veins/base/modules/BaseMacLayer.cc:74:29: error: cast from pointer to smaller type 'LAddress::L2Type' (aka 'long') loses information
                myMacAddr = LAddress::L2Type(addressString.c_str());
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:165: ../out/clang-release/src/veins/base/modules/BaseMacLayer.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/SIA/Omnet/omnetpp-5.1pre2-src-windows/omnetpp-5.1pre2/samples/veins/src'
make: *** [Makefile:12: all] Error 2
19:58:08 Build Finished (took 3s.360ms)**
```

Appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

Though, admittedly, this also points to an underlying inconsistency in the code, Veins 4.4 is a simulation module library for OMNeT++ 4.6. It is also compatible with OMNeT++ 5.0.

You are using a version of OMNeT++ (5.1 pre-release) that Veins is not compatible with.

This means that a downgrade of your OMNeT++ installation should rectify the build error.

The Veins tutorial on http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/ goes into more detail of which software needs to be installed (and how) for Veins to work.